# How to iterate through an array sequentially, where the sequence is stored as another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sequence

Here's the idea:

```
var alphabet = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"]; 
var sequence1 = ["[i]","[i+2]","[i+2]","[i+1]","[i+4]"];
```

So basically I want to iterate through 'alphabet' using the sequence 'sequence1', such that the return would be: `A, C, E, F, J.`

I'll be having many different sequences, so it's necessary that they're each stored as their own array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using `sequence1` to describe how to jump from one term in the output sequence to the next, so try something like this:

```
var alphabet = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"],
    sequence1 = [0,2,2,1,4],
    pos = 0,
    newSeq = [];

for (var i = 0, l = sequence1.length; i < l; i++) {
    pos += sequence1[i];

    if (alphabet[pos] !== undefined) {newSeq.push(alphabet[pos]);}
}
```

which will produce an array `newSeq` that should be what you want.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/uSmg5/

Answer (score 0):

You can store the sequence as integers and then iterate through `alphabet` such as this:

```
var alphabet  = ["A", "B", "C", ...];
var sequence1 = [0, 2, 2, 1, 4];

for (var i = 0; i < sequence1.length; i++) {
   alphabet[sequence1[i]+i];
}
```

Note that, for eventual output to be `A, C, E, F, J`. The sequence should be `0, 1, 2, 2, 3` because arrays starts at index 0, not index 1.

Comment: `alphabet[sequence1[i]+i]` - what's that supposed to mean?

Comment: It's supposed to mean exactly that.

Comment: Exactly what? That's a no-op.